# Should we use (’s) with Sunday's Supper?

Tags: possessives

Should we use apostrophe s (’s) with *Sunday's Supper*?

> For Sunday's supper, Asimov was pulling together a wine pairing ... [OC Weekly](http://www.ocweekly.com/restaurants/three-seventy-common-has-a-common-denominator-6420696)

I noticed that (’s) is quite use with Sunday's Supper:

[image]

Shouldn't we use (’s) when something belongs to someone or something? but supper doesn't belong to Sunday, does it?

I think it shouldn't be a *possessive form*, I think it should be *Noun as Adjective*. Am I right?

For **Sunday supper**, Asimov was pulling together a wine pairing ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sunday supper means dinner on any Sunday. **After church on Sundays, the family sits down to Sunday dinner.**

**Sunday's supper** refers to that specific meal. On that Sunday, he paired wine with the food.

Answer (score 3):

In your *specific* context it's entirely a stylistic choice whether to use the Saxon genitive (**'s**).

Arguably, *Sunday's supper* is a slightly atypical example in this area. If it had been *Sunday **dinner***, the apostrophe would rarely be included - but it usually would be in, say, ***Thursday's*** supper.

The reason for this is that the *noun as adjective* (noun adjunct, attributive noun) usage tends to be reserved for contexts where what's being referenced is something *known, familiar to the speaker*.

Native speakers know that *Sunday dinner* is a particular *kind* of meal, so it's actually credible to say something like *I sometimes have Sunday dinner on Saturday* (it'll be understood to mean a [Sunday roast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday_roast), regardless of the apparent "day mismatch").

But if you said *I'm having Thursday supper on Friday this week*, people would look at you askew. They'd have to suppose that *you* know exactly what you (either in general, or specifically in your meal plan for the coming week) have for supper on Thursday(s), but *they* wouldn't normally know what that meal might be, so it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Interesting point on how this works with _Sunday_ but not with, say, _Thursday_.

Comment: @J.R.: I should probably have clarified things a bit more. Essentially the possessive identifies a *specific* Sunday in OP's example, as per Willow's answer. So without **'s** in my final example, it's a reference to *the kind of supper people in general typically have on (any) Thursday* - which doesn't really work because there isn't such a thing as a "typical Thursday supper". My example would still be a bit unusual if I'd included the possessive - but at least it would make sense, given the implication that at least ***I*** have such a concept (even if my audience don't know what it is! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are partly correct.

Generally, a supper on Sunday may be referred to as

> Sunday supper

however, the author may be using

> Sunday's supper *(possessive)*

to emphasize *the upcoming* supper on Sunday.

Comment: or a previous Sunday -- a specific Sunday...

Comment: @WillowRex  Yes, a *specific* Sunday, I've assumed, without additional context, he is referring to the coming Sunday.